# No API available during Postman configuration. Why?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Microsoft has documented the process to use Postman with Azure B2C [Use Postman to get a token and test the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi#use-postman-to-get-a-token-and-test-the-api).

At step 3 In the Select API dropdown, select the name of the web API. My dropdown list is empty.

[image]

I have no idea why because I have a Web API registered

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just didn't set the **App ID URI** for your webapi application.

[image]

Select **Published scopes** and verify the default `user_impersonation` scope is present.

[image]

Comment: Yes. Setting up App ID URI is the solution for me. Thank you. I followed the step on link provided by the tutorial then considered all other information on main page as duplicate. I missed this part. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to create an app representing your web api / resource. And create scopes there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications#register-a-web-app

Once you create this app, then when you create Postman app, you can grant consent  to Postman app for your resource app created earlier.

Comment: This is already done. Look at my screenshot. The API is created, first line,  so why I don't see it?

Comment: I didn't generated a key... Except that I followed this tutorial to register my API.

Comment: Now I generated the key. Still not working. I will post details of my settings later but I followed the registration tutorial step by step with jwt.ms as url reply.